# $\mathbf H R$ is a ring spectrum if $R$ is a ring

Tags: stable-homotopy-theory, spectra

The first example of a ring spectrum is probably the Eilenberg-McLane spectrum of a ring $R$. But how is the multiplication $\mu: \mathbf H R \wedge \mathbf H R \to \mathbf H R$ defined? Probably this is so trivial that no book includes an explanation, but I really can not figure this out.

I am using the basic definition of spectra as sequential, possibly CW-, spectra given by Adams, I have found details on the multiplication on Schwede's book on symmetric spectra, but I am still not comfortable with those.

Comment: Just a comment since I don't want to take the time to write details, but $H$ can be made into a functor, and then this $\mu$ is just $H$ applied to the multiplication map $R \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} R \to R$. This is using the fact that $H(R \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} R)$ is equivalent to $HR \wedge HR$.

Comment: Another way to think about this is to use the fact that $HR$ represents singular cohomology, and since singular cohomology has a ring structure the Yoneda lemma gives $\mu$.